# Is there a way to protect a file in any way so that other superusers CANNOT modify, delete or overwrite it?

Tags: permissions, sudo, users, parameter

When entering a `sudo command file` is there a way to set a parameter(s) which locks the file afterward so it cannot be modified, deleted, or overwritten by **any other superusers**?

*More specifically:* I want to set up an announcement and place it in the home folder of each user's `/home/announcements/` folder.

> This is a test to see if I
>   can insert a file into each 
>   user's announcements folder.
>
> It is also a test of whether 
>   I can do this and disallow 
>   other regular and superusers 
>   from modifying or deleting it 
>   without my own personal 
>   user privileges.

So, is that situation described above possible?

E.g. would adding the following after writing and saving the above help?

```
sudo chmod -rv 644 /home/*/announcements/announcement-1
```

~or if it's executable~

```
sudo chmod -rv 744 /home/*/announcements/announcement-1
```

<sub>**Note:** I have dyslexia and sometimes translating from *mentalese* into actual written/spoken language can be challenging for me. Tell me if you need me to clarify anything.</sub>

Comment: Forcing an immutable file into user directories is not a very good idea. I'd rather put the announcement into a shared directory and use `notify-send` to tell users to go have a look when they log in, if `/etc/motd` is not a feasible option.

Answer (score 4):

1. `root` *has access to everything*, so depending what you call "superusers" the answer is "maybe" or "no".¹
2. For regular users you can:

   ```
   chown root:root /home/*/announcements/announcement-1
   chmod a-wt /home/*/announcements/announcement-1
   chmod a+r /home/*/announcements/announcement-1
   ```

   Meaning respectively line by line:
   a. Change the owner on your announcement to root
   b. Remove write and sticky bit from the announcement
   c. Give everyone read access only.

<sub>**Note 1:** if your definition of "superuser" = "has sudo access", the answer is **No!** (sorry!); if something else: *Maybe, please clarify*.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

The closest you can get without significant work involving things like SELinux is to make the file immutable via:

```
chattr +i /path/to/file
```

If the immutable flag is set for a file, nobody can write, append, move, delete, or in any other way change the file at the filesystem level or above without first unsetting the immutable flag.  This still has two issues:

- There's no way to prevent someone with root access from unsetting the immutable flag.
- There's no way to prevent someone with access to the storage device the filesystem that the file is in is stored on from just modifying the file data directly.

Once you factor in SELinux or other MAC systems, you can *probably* do what you want, but it's going to take a lot of effort to pull it off.

All that said, you should not be giving root access to people you don't trust.

Also, potentially of note, you can't achieve this on Windows either, anybody with access to the Administrator account (not an account listed as an administrator, but the actual 'Administrator' account) can bypass pretty much any permissions checks just like the root user on UNIX systems can.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible.

Proof:

1. The most obvious: a superuser can do `su ev`, or create and run a program that performs the underlying system call. After this, they can issue the “unlock” command, since they can do whatever you can do.
2. In any case, they don't even need to do that (and so it's pointless do try to block specific commands like `su ev` — it's also pointless because it wouldn't work anyway). Almost permission checks allow user 0 to do whatever any other user can do. There are a few exceptions (such as accessing a FUSE filesystem), but once a user is root, they can just run code as any other user (see 1).

Note that by “superuser”, I assume you mean “superuser”, i.e. a user who has administrative privileges on the machine. It is possible to cheat in several ways:

- You can keep superuser rights for yourself and allow other people only access to some specific commands that do not allow running arbitrary code. For example a user who can run `sudo reboot` is not a superuser. A user who can run `sudo sh`, `sudo tee` or `sudo mount` is a superuser.
- Some security frameworks such as SELinux allow setting up access to an account with user ID 0 (i.e. root), but with restrictions that prevent this account from doing anything that a non-root account cannot do. It's really hard to set up correctly, and mostly pointless in practice since there's no point in giving someone access to user ID 0 if they don't get privileges from it.
- You can give everybody else superuser rights in a virtual machine or in a container, but keep superuser rights on the host to yourself.